# bash - can shellcode be made from a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, c

I was thinking it can't, since there's not really a binary for bash scripts, but having to write a C program every time you need to generate shell code for a single command is just a pain.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: You want a translator from C to bash ? What exactly do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use programs from [metasploit](https://www.metasploit.com/) to generate shellcode.

Here's an example using msfpayload to do so:

http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/tips-and-trick/generate-a-shellcode-using-msfpayload-metasploit-command-line-instance/

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible thanks to my new malware tool

git clone https://github.com/Radicalware/Malware_Tools

It does exactly what you asked for.
It also works to make Windows shellcode as well as Linux/OSX.

This is NOT like metasploit/shellsploit which generate shellcodes and only taylor them to your needs (ip,port,username,etc), my tool actually allows you to CREATE your own shellcodes from scratch!!!